# How to strip trailing space in docstring in pycharm

Tags: pycharm

Anyone know how I can set up pycharm configuration to trailing space in docstring in pycharm? I research online and find this question [PyCharm does not strip trailing whitespaces in docstrings](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000244490-PyCharm-does-not-strip-trailing-whitespaces-in-docstrings) but it seems like there is no solid solution. I have most updated pycharm version and tried to set up *Always keep trailing spaces on caret line* or  *Strip trailing spaces on Save* in all difference combination. but none of them works. the step I use is

```
1: under function, type """"""
2: move caret between 3rd and 4th "
3: click enter to generate docstring automatically
```

[image]

Comment: What seems to be the problem ? It doesn't generate docs when you press `Enter` after third quotes?

Comment: it doesnot trim trailing space after I press enter to generate docstring

Comment: Sorry, still don't get it. I generate docs by placing caret on name of function or class and pressing `Alt+Enter` and it asks me what to generate docs from parameters and do I want to include return type, use type annotations etc.

Comment: attached image.. after I generate doc string, there are extra space at the end of *:param arg1: * and *:param arg2: * how can i set up my pycharm so I wont have extra space?